# Problem in restricted 3 edge coloring

Tags: combinatorics

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzklG.jpg)

Suppose we color the edges of $K_n$ with colors Black, White and Red so that at most $n^2/k$ of the edges are colored Red.

- Show that the graph contains either a Black $K_p$ or a White $K_p$ with $p = \frac{1}{100}\log{k}$
- Show that there is a coloring of $K_n$ with colors Black, White and Red so that at most $n^2/k$ of the edges are colored Red, and yet the resulting graph does not contain either a Black $K_p$ or a White $K_p$ with $p = 100\log{k}$

I am not sure how to incorporate Ramsey theory to solve the above problem.

Comment: There is no problem.

Comment: Edited, sorry :)

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.

Comment: Edited again :)

Comment: Is there a reason this appeared almost simultaneously with [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809662)?